# How to restrict Leaflet-control-geocoder results by city or bbox?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding

I'm trying to restrict results of [Leaflet geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder) (using the Nominatim provider) to one city by using `geocodingQueryParams`. But suggestions and results are still for whole world. I've tried several modifications (`geocodingQueryParams:'liberec'` / `geocodingQueryParams:'city=liberec'` / `geocodingQueryParams:'q=liberec'`) but with no success. Do you have some suggestions? Or is it possible to filter by bbox in this plugin?

My code:

```
var geocoder=L.Control.geocoder({
    placeholder: 'Hledej...',
    errorMessage: 'Nenašli jsme :(',
    defaultMarkGeocode: false,
    geocoder: new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim({
        geocodingQueryParams:'liberec'
        })
})
.on('markgeocode', function(e) {
    var bbox = e.geocode.bbox;
    var poly = L.polygon([
         bbox.getSouthEast(),
         bbox.getNorthEast(),
         bbox.getNorthWest(),
         bbox.getSouthWest()
    ]);
    map.fitBounds(poly.getBounds());
}).addTo(map);
```

I'm using Leaflet version 1.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me quote [Nominatim's documentation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#parameters):

> #### Result limitation
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> viewbox=<x1>,<y1>,<x2>,<y2>
> ```
>
> The preferred area to find search results. Any two corner points of the box are accepted in any order as long as they span a real box.

Also, note that [the `geocodingQueryParams` option from Leaflet-control-geocoder's Nominatim provider](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#options-1) takes an `Object`, not a `String`; URL query parameters are usually given as a set of key-value pairs, with the parameter name as the key and the parameter value as the value.

Therefore, you can do something like:

```
var geocoder=L.Control.geocoder({
    geocoder: new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim({
        geocodingQueryParams: {
            "viewbox": "14.07,49.02,24.02,54.85"
        }
    })
});
```

If you have an instance of `L.LatLngBounds` instead of a `<x1>,<y1>,<x2>,<y2>`  string, you can leverage [`toBBoxString()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#latlngbounds-tobboxstring):

```
var bbox = L.latLngBounds(/* stuff */);

var geocoder=L.Control.geocoder({
    geocoder: new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim({
        geocodingQueryParams: {
            "viewbox": bbox.toBBoxString()
        }
    })
});
```

---

Nominatim also allows for `country` and `city` parameters, but those are [structured query parameters](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#parameters), only to be used when there's no query string. The following will **NOT** work as expected:

```
var geocoder=L.Control.geocoder({
    geocoder: new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim({
        geocodingQueryParams: {
            "country": "FR",
            "city": "Paris"
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I found another missing parameter 'bounded':1 in case of viewbox. Without this it was not working. But thanks a lot, it works! :)